# Can I initialize an STL vector with 10 of the same integer in an initializer list?

Tags: c++, stl, constructor, initializer-list

Can I initialize an STL vector with 10 of the same integer in an initializer list?  My attempts so far have failed me.

Comment: There's a [`std::vector<>` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (2) that does that; why would you want an initializer list?

Comment: @ildjarn: I think he means in a constructor initialization list, and not in the constructor body.

Comment: @GManNickG: It doesn't sound like that to me.  The OP asks for a way to initialize a vector with X number of elements all set to the same value.  Yes, he does mention an initialization list, but seeing as there is already a constructor which meets the *requirement* that should be good enough

Comment: @EdS.: To clarify, I think the OP is asking how to do this: `struct foo { foo() : INIT_HERE {} };` rather than this: `struct foo { foo() { INIT_HERE; } };`.

Comment: Yes GManNickG that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Use the appropriate constructor, which takes a size and a default value.

```
int number_of_elements = 10;
int default_value = 1;
std::vector<int> vec(number_of_elements, default_value);
```

Comment: Thx, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 36):

I think you mean this:

```
struct test {
   std::vector<int> v;
   test(int value) : v( 100, value ) {}
};
```

Comment: @Cokemonkey11: This answer is *not* documented at all, you can find the documentation in your favorite reference (mine is cppreference). It is *not* more complicated than necessary, without the class and the constructor Ed S.'s answer does not initialize a vector *in an initializer list*, which is part of the question. For this case it would not matter much, but consider if the question was about an array of ints, initialization in the stack and as part of the initializer list are different.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using C++11 and on GCC, you could do this:

```
vector<int> myVec () {[0 ... 99] = 1};
```

It's called ranged initialization and is a GCC-only extension.

Comment: Wow, I've never even heard of that. Of course, it's better to just use the right constructor.

Comment: Yep. But this comes handy for arrays and structs. Anyway, GCC has a bunch of extensions that do crazy things. Best stick to standard C++.

Comment: The "Designated Initializers" extension in only available for C code, not C++. For the list of the available GCC extensions see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html#C_002b_002b-Extensions

Answer (score 8):

The initialization list for vector is supported from C++0x. If you compiled with C++98

```
int number_of_elements = 10;
int default_value = 1;
std::vector<int> vec(number_of_elements, default_value);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do that with `std::vector` constructor:

```
vector(size_type count, 
                 const T& value,
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Which takes `count` and `value` to be repeated.

If you want to use initializer lists you can write:

```
const int x = 5;
std::vector<int> vec {x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x};
```

Answer (score 0):

can you post what you are doing

```
 int i = 100;
vector<int> vInts2 (10, i);

vector<int>::iterator iter;
for(iter = vInts2.begin(); iter != vInts2.end(); ++iter)
{
    cout << " i " << (*iter) << endl;
}
```