# which is best way to initialize array, "memset" or " {//value} "?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

```
int main(){

int ar[50]={1};

//OR

int br[50];

memset(br, 1, sizeof(br)); 

return 0;

}
```

Comment: ar[50]={1}; only sets the first value in the array to 1, not the entire array contents

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I initialize an STL vector with 10 of the same integer in an initializer list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237751/can-i-initialize-an-stl-vector-with-10-of-the-same-integer-in-an-initializer-lis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int ar[50]={1};
```

This will set only the first element to `1`. Rest all will be `0`.

```
memset(br, 1, sizeof(br));
```

This will set all the *bytes* in `br` to 1. It is not the same as setting all the values to `1`. The values afterwards are:

```
{16843009, 16843009, 16843009, 16843009, 16843009}
```

Use `memset` when you know you really need it. It is not exactly made for initializing arrays, it just set the memory to a particular value.

Best way in C++? Use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) or [`std::fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n).

Example:

```
int array[5];
std::fill(array, array + 5, 8);
```

Array now contains:

```
{8, 8, 8, 8, 8}
```

Using `fill_n`

```
std::fill_n(array, 5, 99);
```

Array now contains:

```
{99, 99, 99, 99, 99}
```

As a side note, prefer using `std::array` instead of c-style arrays.

Try on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/DmgTGE

References:
[1] : [Array Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization)
[2] : [memset doc](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

suppose you do

```
int ar[50] = {-1};
```

Now you will expect this line to initialize all array elements with -1
but it will not. It will only set the first element of array to -1 and rest to 0.
 Whereas memset will show the expected behaviour.

See this [Initialization of all elements of an array to one default value in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/initialization-of-all-elements-of-an-array-to-one-default-value-in-c/1065800#1065800) for more info.

let's take an example:-

```
int arr[5] = { 1, 2 }; // this will initialize to 1,2,0,0,0



int ar[5] = {  }; // this will  initialize  all elements 0



int myArray[10] = {}; // his will also all elements 0 in C++ not in c
```

So If you want to initialize a specific value to an array use memset().

If you want to initialize all elements in an array to 0 use

```
static int myArray[10]; // all elements 0
```

Because objects with static storage duration will initialize to 0 if no initializer is specified and it is more portable than memset().

Also, The `int ar[50]={0};` will be infinite because it just  initializes the array and  does not have an ending but in `memset(arr,0,sizeof(br))` it has the correct way of ending the loop in arrays